# Laravel 5 & Webpack SASS - How to Add Another CSS File

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, compilation, sass

I´m trying to add another file to webpack.mix.js in Laravel 5.4, but when I do that, I have an error in compilation.

This works:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

This doesn't work:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/web.scss', 'public/css');
```

How can I add another CSS to webpack into separate files?

**EDIT**

The error:

> npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0 npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev" npm ERR! node v6.10.0 npm ERR! npm v3.10.10 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! @ dev: node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=$npm_package_config_webpack npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=$npm_package_config_webpack'

Comment: Just be clear are you wanting to have both `app.scss` and `web.scss` be compiled in to separate files or the same file?

Comment: I want to have both in to separate files

Comment: This compile the first file: app.scss but the second have the error:

Comment: npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=$npm_package_config_webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=$npm_package_config_webpack'.

Comment: Thanks for the correction ;)

Comment: One thing you could try is deleting your node_modules directory and then reinstalling your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Ross Wilson. Now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution provided by Ross Wilson:

*One thing you could try is deleting your node_modules directory and then reinstalling your dependencies (npm install).*

It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to append all of the scss files into a array like so

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass([
   'resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 
   'resources/assets/sass/web.scss'], 'public/css');
```

This will output a single CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, GNewton, but this give me an error: assert.js:85
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^
AssertionError: mix.Sass() is missing required parameter 1: src

Comment: This does not work, you can't pass an array to mix.sass()